# is the Atmel AT32UC 3C supported in freeRTOS?

Tags: c, freertos, avr32

I have an Atmel AT32UC 3C which I want to use. I'm just getting started with freeRTOS. I'm using Eclipse IDE along with MingW gcc compiler, and I downloaded FreeRTOS v8.2.3, v9.0.0 and v10.2.1. The problem is I can't find a demo example for AT32UC 3C; only AT 32UC 3A and 3B are available. Am I missing sth??

Comment: To begin with, Mingw is the Windows port of gcc. You can't use that, you need a compiler ported to the Atmel MCU you are using ("cross compiler"). I would also avoid Eclipse like the plague it is. Even Atmel Studio is a better IDE.

Comment: Would you please explain more of why you would avoid Eclipse as an IDE ??

Comment: Atmel stopped using the eclipse based IDE for AVR32, like, 8 years ago.  You really want to be using AVR32-GCC in atmel studio (or IAR if you're rich).

Comment: @ibtissamlatachi Mostly because: bugs, bugs and more bugs. It is the worst IDE ever made, all categories. You'll constantly find yourself debugging strange linker errors caused by the IDE instead of debugging your own code. Atmel Studio is ok and free. Or you can fork up the money for a professional IDE like Crossworks or IAR.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [listed ports](https://www.freertos.org/RTOS_ports.html) on the freeRTOS website, AVR32 UC3 is supported. If you follow the [Atmel link](https://www.freertos.org/a00090.html#ATMEL) on the previous page, there is this disclaimer:

> These demos can be adapted to any microcontroller within the same family that has sufficient ROM/RAM. See the Creating a new application and Adapting a Demo pages.

You can find an example [there](http://simplemachines.it/martin/mizar32/1.6.0-AT32UC3/SERVICES/FREERTOS/Demo/AVR32_UC3/DOC/html/index.html) (this is not the official website anymore).

Comment: Ok. so, it doesn t matter if it's an Atmel AT32UC 3C or 3B or 3A. All I need is to use the AVR32 UC3. Thank you :)

Comment: It didn't say that it doesn't matter, it says that it just needs some adaptations.

Answer (score 1):

The only key difference between UC3A and UC3C is UC3C has an FPU. It will run fine.

Answer (score 0):

THe AVR32 port [shipped with FreeRTOS](https://www.freertos.org/portAVR32.html) was written for original AVR32 chips and has some known issues when run on the latest chips - therefore recommend using the FreeRTOS AVR32 port that ships with Atmel Studio itself.